# How to handle rpc/literal webservice with JAXB2 and Spring-WS

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jaxb, spring-ws

We need to access a legacy webservice that uses the RPC/literal webservice style  and also to provide webservice endpoints for it. If you use webservices of document/literal style with Spring WebserviceTemplates / WebserviceEndpoints, you can use JAXB2 to generate / marshal / unmarshal the webservice requests. But how do you do this with RPC/literal style? The org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin does not seem to be able to generate Java classes for the requests / responses.

Answer (score 4):

With rpc/literal you will be stuck in the dark ages of Axis 1.4

Spring-WS or Jax-WS won't help you here as the concentrate on WS-I Basic Profile compliant document/literal services.